# How to traverse an array in reverse direction in dust.js?

Tags: dust.js

Is there any simple solution, or it can be accomplished only by defining a custom helper?

Answer (score 1):

The best solution is probably to have the server send the array in reverse order to begin with. In most cases, the "Dust way" is to have the server send data in the format that it will be presented by Dust. If you don't have control over how the data is sent, though, you will either need a helper, or you can manipulate the data (using JavaScript) before passing it to `dust.render`.

```
var data = getData();
var data.arrayToReverse = reverseArray(data.arrayToReverse);
dust.render('myDustTemplate', data, function(err, out) {
    // Show the result.
});
```

You would need to write the `getData` and `reverseArray` methods, but this way you *could* get the reversed array without a helper.

Comment: I can't modify the underlying data in any way, neither on server side nor in javascript.

Comment: Then a helper is probably your best bet.